# How do I add a class to my unordered list in Weebly?

Tags: html, css, weebly

Weebly help center can't help me on this simple one and they recommended the forums, google and w3schools. I wan't to style my `<ul></ul>` in weebly by adding a class to it. How do I do this?

Comment: I can't add the tag **"weebly"** because it needs 1500 reputation but this post should be tagged as **"weebly"**, FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, I override the standard theme design rather than create my own.
These are the CSS parts I modified: `#main-wrap .paragraph ul` and `#main-wrap .paragraph ol`

```
#main-wrap .paragraph ul {
    padding-left:5px !important;
}

#main-wrap .paragraph ul li {
    list-style: none !important;
background: url(red-arrow.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
    color: #000000;
    padding-left:30px !important;
}

#main-wrap .paragraph ol li {
    list-style: none !important;
    background: url(red-bullet.png) no-repeat 0px 6px;
    color: #000000;
    padding-left:20px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, Weebly's [support documentation](http://themedocs.weebly.com/css.html) says your backend will have a tab to manage your CSS and HTML.

**Option one**

1 - Go to the HTML tab and add a class to your `ul`.

```
<ul class="myClass"></ul>
```

2 - Go to the CSS tab and *at the bottom* of the main css file write in your new class style

```
.myClass { /* whatever */}
```

By placing the class at the bottom of your CSS, these class styles will override the current styles if they are different. You may need to cancel out certain things like `margin` or `padding`. For instance:

```
ul { margin: 100px; }

.myClass { margin: 0; }
```

`.myClass` will have a margin of 0 as the `ul`s defined style has been overridden.

---

**Option two**

Wrap your editable content in a div with a class or id and target the ul within that div. The `div` itself can remain unstyled.

Example

HTML

```
<div id="editableContent">

    <ul>
        <li>List Item</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#editableContent ul {
    color: #F00;
}
```

Every list item within `div#editableContent` will have red text. The editor doesn't need any HTML knowledge and styles will be consistent.

Comment: I can't use html code when creating the list, it should be editable by the user or the next admin of the website when it is done. you know what I mean? The list could be dynamically created. (weebly has a very poor documentation, sad to say)

Comment: Would you not just generate the list with a class name?

Comment: I am creating this website using weebly and when this is finished i will be passing it to the admin or the one to maintain the website. Let's assume he want's to add another entry to the list but he doesn't know how to HTML. What I want to do is: when the user creates a list, weebly will attach a class to the list instead of the user creating the list using HTML code. have you tried using Weebly?

Comment: I imagine it works the same as other template engines. If they are creating a new list (i.e. not just adding and removing items from an existing `ul`) then wrap the content section that they will be editing  with a `div` and target all ul elements within it. For example you could have `<div id="editableContent">` with the CSS `#editableContent ul` and `#editableContent li`.